# build new DUKTAPE js object from c with native-c construstor

Tags: duktape

i'm trying to build JS object fully in C, similar as the following **JS**:

```
var _a = function(p){
    this.p = p;           
}

_a.prototype.myFunction= function(){ ...; }

var _b = function(){
   this.sub = new _a(p);
}

exports.A = A;
exports.B = B;
```

The fact that is used it into NodeJS module like, is important, because neither A and B are globally accessible.

In order to do so i wrote the following pattern in **C**:

```
duk_ret_t _js_a_dtor(duk_context *ctx) {
}

duk_ret_t _js_a_ctor(duk_context *ctx) {

    if (!duk_is_constructor_call(ctx)) {
        return DUK_RET_TYPE_ERROR;
    }

    // Push special this binding to the function being constructed
    duk_push_this(ctx);

    // Store the function destructor
    duk_push_c_function(ctx, _js_a_dtor, 0);
    duk_set_finalizer(ctx, -2);
    return 0;
}

duk_ret_t _js_a_myFunction(duk_context *ctx) {
...
}

static const duk_function_list_entry _js_a_funcs[] = {
    { "", _js_a_myFunction, 0 },
    { NULL, NULL, 0 }
};


duk_ret_t _js_b_dtor(duk_context *ctx) {
}

duk_ret_t _js_b_ctor(duk_context *ctx) {

    if (!duk_is_constructor_call(ctx)) {
        return DUK_RET_TYPE_ERROR;
    }

    // Push special this binding to the function being constructed
    duk_push_this(ctx);

    duk_push_c_function(ctx, _js_a_ctor, 0);
    duk_new(ctx,0);
    duk_put_prop_string(ctx,"sub");

    // Store the function destructor
    duk_push_c_function(ctx, _js_b_dtor, 0);
    duk_set_finalizer(ctx, -2);
    return 0;
}

void duk_init_class(duk_context *ctx, void * ctor, int paramsCount, duk_function_list_entry * func, char * className)
{
    // Create object function
    duk_push_c_function(ctx, ctor, paramsCount);       // [{exports},{ctor}]

    // Create a prototype with all functions
    duk_push_object(ctx);                              // [{exports}, { ctor }, {}]
    duk_put_function_list(ctx, -1, func);              // [{exports}, { ctor }, {}]
    duk_put_prop_string(ctx, -2, DUK_PROTOTYPE_NAME);  // [{exports}, { ctor }]

    // Now store the object function
    duk_put_prop_string(ctx, -2, className);           // [{exports}]
}
```

but as i suspected, the prototype of a, is not correctly set when calling duk_new, and any attempt to use function on a failed in **JS**

```
var m = require('mymodule');
var a = new m.A();  // working
a.myFunction();     // working
var b = new m.B();  // working
b.sub ;             // defined
b.sub.myFunction(); // failed while myFunction is undefined..
```

Any idea on how to fix this ??
i already know that i can put the constructor in the global but i guess if there is another direct alternative to bind the prototype with the c function...

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duktape/C functions don't have a `.prototype` property by default so when they are called as constructors, the instances created will inherit from Object.prototype. To change that, you can simply set the `.prototype` property of the function.

So if I understood correctly, in your case you can do something like:

```
/* Build prototype object, here: { myFunction: ... } */
duk_push_object(ctx);
duk_push_c_function(ctx, _js_a_myFunction, ...);
duk_put_prop_string(ctx, -2, "myFunction");

/* Set A.prototype. */
duk_put_prop_string(ctx, idx_for_A_ctor, "prototype");
```

If you're using duk_put_function_list(), you'll need to read the constructor function value from the target object so that you can set its `.prototype`.

Comment: Hello Sami and thanks for your response. For clarification, i add the duk_init_class function which i use to declare my function and bind prototype to.

Comment: however, when call the B constructor and then the inner A constructor (using c function) i do not have any way to get the correct prototype..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem, but if the problem is simply how to find 'A' inside the constructor 'B' there are various ways to solve that, just like in JS code. You could place a reference to the global object, or if you prefer the reference to be hidden from JS code, to the global "stash" which is only visible to C code. You could also write a reference to the B object itself (say B.A = A) and use duk_push_current_function() inside B to get access to B, and then look up property "A".